# Blu-ray playback in Power DVD is in black and white and with lines

Tags: blu-ray, powerdvd

Relevant system specs:

Intel i3-530
Gigabyte [GA-H55M-UD2H](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=3503#ov)
Samsung SH-B083A Blu-ray/DVD Combo Drive
Windows 7
Power DVD 8 (OEM) and Power DVD 10 Ultra (Trial version)
Samsung Plasma (via HDMI)

When I try and play a Blu-Ray (Star Trek - the only one I own), I see images like the following (sorry for the phone camera but you can't take screenshots when Power DVD is open):

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

When I open the Cyberlink BD Advisor (which is supposed to show if your system is Blu-Ray ready), I see this:

[image]

Obviously it came out before Windows 7, hence why the OS isn't showing up. The graphics driver is the latest one from the Gigabyte website and is time-stamped at 2010/04/27 so there's no way it could be out of date.

The drive came with PowerDVD 8 but I've tried the trial version of PowerDVD 10 and the same thing happens. Any clues as to what could be going wrong?

Comment: This is a long shot but on the link you provided to your motherboard "Note 2" tells us you must have a CPU with integrated graphics.  What CPU are you running?  Also, have you tried any other players?  I would install the K-Lite Codec Pack and try to play your BD with Media Player Classic (MPC) which comes with it.  It is free and I know I like it a lot better than most players out there.

Comment: @typoknig: CPU is an i3 530 which has integrated graphics. I didn't realised that MPC can play Blu Rays so I'll give that a shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the same Blu-Ray worked in [TotalMedia Theatre 3 Platinum](http://www.arcsoft.com/estore/software_title.asp?ProductCode=TMT3P) so I'm just going to give up on Power DVD.

Comment: Did you ever give MPC a try?

Comment: I didn't bother to install it - you have to use AnyDVD first, it would seem: http://forum.doom9.org/archive/index.php/t-148854.html